# How to create a UWP Package that`s shipping Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0 with it

Tags: deployment, package, uwp, mdm

I`m struggling with the following issue:

I try to deploy my uwp app with a Mobile Device Management System (MobileIron). it's only accepts .appxbundle, no .appxupload files. When i try to install/deploy the app on a device, i get the error

> Can not install package XY because the package xy has a dependency to Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0. This package is needed for the installation. Deploy this Framework together with your package

(my custom translation ;) )

The problem is, I dont know how to create a package, that's shipping the needed CoreRuntime within. When i create a DEBUG Package, i get a appxbundle and a folder with the missing CoreRuntime.appx, but only the powershell script is shipping the CoreRuntime Framework to the Device, not the bundle itself. 
When i create a RELEASE Package, it`s running agains .NET Native, in this case i have no CoreRuntime...

Hope i explained my problem good enought and someone can help me or give me a hind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable **.NET Native**, From your Project Properties:

Make sure that your configuration is for Release. And check

> Compile with .NET Native tool chain

and

> Optimize code

[image]

finally make sure to create your packages from Store->Create App Packages. With the following configurations:

[image]